# Evaluate the double integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1-\cos(3x+3y)}{2-\cos(x)-\cos(y)}dxdy$

Tags: multiple-integral

$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1-\cos(3x+3y)}{2-\cos(x)-\cos(y)}dxdy$

After applying $\cos(C)+\cos(D)=2\cos\frac{C+D}{2}\cos\frac{C-D}{2}$ this integral reduces to:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1-\cos(3x+3y)}{2\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\right)}dxdy$$

Now assuming that $x+y=t, x-y=u$, I get $x=(t+u)/2, y=(t-u)/2$, I got:
$$\int\int\frac{1-\cos(3t)}{\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)\right)}dtdu$$

How to proceed further?

Comment: You have done almost everything - now you need to calculate the Jacobian, new bounds and integrate.

Comment: @zkutch What about limits of $t$ and $u$? I am not able to determine them.

Comment: Four lines $x,y=0,\pi$ goes to four lines $t+u,t-u=2\pi,0$, so square goes to  rhombus. Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in comments lines $x=0,x=\pi$ converted to lines $t+u=0,t+u=2\pi$ and lines $y=0,y=\pi$ converted to lines $t-u=0,t-u=2\pi$, so for integrals we have
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}dxdy=\int\limits_{-\pi}^{0}\int\limits_{-u}^{2\pi+u}J\  dudt+\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\int\limits_{u}^{2\pi-u}J\  dudt$$
Where Jakobian is $J$.